# Como obtener un get.storage dentro de ngOnInit o constructor?

Tags: angular, ionic

Estoy trabajando con ionic 5, y quiero agregar el storage para el manejo de mis datos, envio mis datos con un formulario que al crear usuario el almacena mis datos `storage.set`..., al pasar de componente quiero recuperar dichos datos, establezco el llamado `storage.get`... en mi `ngOnInit`
pero veo que al cargar dicho componente no me trae al instante la data, si recargo la pagina el los trae sin problema, como puedo solucionar que me cargue la data en mi `ngOnInit`?
he probado colocando el storage.get... en mi constructor y me pasa lo mismo. muchas gracias espero me puedan ayudar.aqui mi codigo:

componente 1:

```
const EMAIL = 'email';

 email:string; //esta variable es la que recibo de mi formulario

constructor( private storage: Storage ) { 

this.storage.set(EMAIL, this.email);
```

componente 2:

```
const EMAIL = 'email';

email:string;

constructor( private storage: Storage ) { }

ngOnInit() {

this.storage.get(EMAIL).then((email)=>{
  this.email = email
  console.log('Email desde el storage: ', 
this.email)
})
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Veamos dos cosas:

1- tu variable email esta declarada pero aun no tiene ningun valor, por lo tanto no estas guardando nada en tu local storage, el valor de dicha variable se debe tener al momento de hacer el login, cuando obtienes una respuesta 200 de tu API.

2- un vez has guardado tu email en local storage puedes obtenerlo en tu metodo `ngOnIni`

```
this.storage.get('email').then(email => {
        if (token != null) {
           console.log('email: '+email)
        }else{
           console.log('no se pudo obtener el email')
        }
    });
```

Comment: Yo capturo el valor de mi variable email desde mi formulario, es decir al llenar el formulario obtengo el valor que el usuario digita allí, ese valor es el que envío en mi storage.

Comment: entonces debes deter un metodo que se ejecuta cuando el usuario presiona el boton ingresar

Comment: tengo mi form, y mis datos en el storage que se envían al darle click en ingresar, se pasa a la otra vista donde quiero recuperar esos datos lo hago con el get en mi ngOnInit, es allí donde no me trae la data, pero si recargo pagina me los trae, entonces no se como hacer para que al pasar al siguiente componente en el ngOnInit me traiga la data sin problemas.